# Duplication of number in AtomicInteger.getAndIncrement()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

When return value is of interest, is it possible that in case of `AtomicInteger.getAndIncrement()`, two threads who call this method will get the same value?

In case of `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()` it makes sense two threads will get different value because of the increment happening first.

Comment: If I truly want a way to get incremental numbers in a multi threaded environment, should I prefer `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()` over `AtomicInteger.getAndIncrement()`

Answer (score 0):

Both `getAndIncrement` and `incrementAndGet` methods guarantee *uniqueness* of return value.

One may think as following relation between these two methods (`a` - variable of `AtomicInteger` class):

```
a.IncrementAndGet() == a.getAndIncrement() + 1
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/15137349/3440745 about actual implementation of these methods.

Answer (score 0):

Both [`incrementAndGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet()) and [`getAndIncrement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndIncrement()) meet your requirement since they will

*Atomically adds the given value to the current value.*

Difference is:

> `incrementAndGet`  return updated value
>
> `getAndIncrement`  return current value